# Azure AD B2C Email Signin Name Storage

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a basic user flow from a recommended policy which allows the user to sign up based on an email address.  I can see the user and their email address in Azure AD, however, i am not able to use the MS Graph API to get the signin name or any other attribute that contains the email address the user users when signing up to B2C.  This is essential - how can i store the email address the user provides so that i can retrieve it using Microsoft Graph?  Many Thanks, Steve

I have used the Ms Graph API to query every attribute associated with a user within Azure AD, and email address is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e-mail address is added to the **signInNames** property of the **user** object.

Currently, [you must use Azure AD Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to read from and write to this **signInNames** property, since Microsoft Graph doesn't support it as yet.

Comment: Just to note that signInNames is a *collection* of name objects. The email address is the name having type:emailAddress.